# ERROR TypeError: this.dashboardService.getData is not a function

Tags: angular

I am getting an error while calling a service from the component.
I am trying to fetch some data from the URL provided which returns JSON.
Every time I run this code, HTML loads successfully but URL is not called as it is giving the error on getData() that it is not a function
Getting error while running this. What approach should be taken to resolve it?

this.dashboardService.getData what is the problem in this line.

```
Here is the code:

**app.component.ts**

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  private apiUrl: "someURL";


  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) { 
    this.getEntries();
  }


  getEntries(){
    this.dashboardService.getData(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data" , data) ;
    })
  }


}



**dashboard.service.ts**

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getData(apiUrl){
    return this.http.get(apiUrl)
     .map((res: Response) => res.json());
   }
}


**app.module.ts**

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [DashboardService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: share your dashboardservice code

Comment: It is already provided

Comment: What is error you are getting?

Comment: Provide your error log please.

Comment: AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: this.dashboardService.getData is not a function
    at AppComponent.getEntries (app.component.ts:21)
    at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:16)
    at createClass (core.js:12439)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12284)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13742)
    at createRootView (core.js:13631)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14339)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11236)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4023)

Comment: Did you debug your code? Just add a debugger in the contructor and check for the value of your service.

Comment: import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http' then add HttpModule in your imports for AppModule

Answer (score 2):

You are missing import of HttpModule in your AppModule

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
    import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DashboardComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
       HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [DashboardService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: HttpClientModule ahead of HttpModule would be appropriate

Comment: Agreed, the implementation fr service would change too. Adding it as an alternate

Answer (score 2):

Even though the error is **this.dashboardService.getData** it uses the HttpClientModule, since you do not have the HttpClientModule imported under imports it throws error.

to fix , add

```
 import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/http';
```

also add it under imports.

```
imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       HttpClientModule
]
```

app.under module.ts

also inside your dashboardService

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){
}
```